# React-JavaScript purpose of a line in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very simple question but I am in the learning process and after reading around I could not find a good explanation to this, in the code below:
What is the purpose of the line:

```
this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
```

If I comment it, the program is still working. Most likely with some side effects but I don't know them yet...

```
class test extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    //this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
}

buttonClicked() {
    alert("thank you!")
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.text}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.buttonClicked}>click me!</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: It binds the execution scope of the callback to the current class. So referring to `this` in the callback will refer to your component instance

Comment: *Most likely with some side effects but I dont know them yet* - try `alert(this.props.text)` instead.

Comment: You could avoid using the binding and still access **this** by using arrow function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);`

This line basically allows you to use `this` within your `buttonClicked()` function.

You don't notice a difference since you don't actually use `this` in that function.

Try something with `this` within `buttonClicked()` with the binding line commented out, and you should get an error.

To avoid needing to manually bind, you can use an arrow function, like:

```
buttonClicked = () => {
  // do something with `this`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bind` is used to bind the context. Explanation is already given in other answers.

you can use the following syntax instead of the commented line

```
onClick={this.buttonClicked.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Note: This creates a new function in every render.